# DataTables and php json_encode

Tags: json, datatables

I want to use jQuery(1.10.2)/DataTables (1.9.4) with PHP/json_encode.

The code:

```
#First test.
$response=array();
foreach(array_slice($personList,0,10) as $person){
 $response[]=array($person["firstname"],$person["surename"]);
}
$data=array(
 "sEcho"=> 1,
 "iTotalRecords"=> "10",
 "iTotalDisplayRecords"=> "10",
 "aaData"=> $response);

 echo json_encode($data);
 return;

//Second test.
echo '{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"10","iTotalDisplayRecords":"10","aaData":[["John","Roland"],["Ian","McDonald"],["Henry","Anderson"]]}';
return;
```

The first test doesn't work, when set in comment and running the second, it works. The data of the second is copied from output of the first in Firefox. I get for the first in DataTables "No matching records found".

JS code:

```
$('#personsTable').dataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "http://server/app/index.php/json/personAll"
});
```

No difference with the following before the "echo":

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

UPDATE: It doesn't work when using the array from the model (DAO) with code:

```
$this->db->order_by("firstname, surename");
$query = $this->db->get('person');
return $query->result_array();
```

Regular strings work. strval doesn't make a difference, oddly also strval(intval()) not...

The table was originally latin1 and is converted using phpmyadmin to "utf8_general_ci". I have exported all tables to SQL, changed in text editor from latin1 to utf8, deleted the tables and reimported them, but no difference.

Comment: Have you checked the console and made sure that you are receiving the data in proper format?

Comment: Console OK (with header), format is also good. It should be the encoding... MySQL db is in utf8_general_ci.

Comment: OK. Looks like after the change of the encoding I had a programming error. It works now. So encoding was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The database was in latin1 and after migrating to utf8_general_ci it worked (correcting some other programming errors).